# Duplicate databases error

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, duplication

I have two Oracle 11gR2 databases on separate servers. I want to duplicate these databases.

For this, I do these steps :

- In auxiliary db :

  - create password file with password that is same if target password
- In target database:

  - Create a pfile and set db_name to auxiliary db
  - in tnsname.ora set the auxiliary db
  - with sqlplus connect to auxiliary db and startup, nomount with pfile.

With rman connect to these db and when I want to duplicate these databases with command below, I have an error that's in attach of this question.

```
Duplicate database to orcl1 with active database spfile nofilenamecheck.
```

Can any one help me?

[image]

Comment: Please copy the error you're getting as text into your question. Images aren't searchable (and the host you used is blocked by some corporate filters).

Answer (score 1):

the error messages you got because you don't have privileges to log in to the server so you need to grant the user the necessary access.

some tips to solve this issue:

1) Mount the remote disk locally (map network drive).

2) Use rman CATALOG command to make the backups available.

3) user has enough privileges on ORACLE level

Comment: i have mount auxiliary database in host db :
(in target databse write this commancd : )sqlplus sys/password@orcl1           
sql>startup nomount pfile='destination';

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your command to start rman, but it appears that you have not connected to both the target and the auxiliary.  You will need something like this:

```
rman TARGET sys/password@source AUXILIARY sys/password@destination
```

I don't think it matters, but you also don't need to have the duplicate command in a run block.

If you haven't already, you may also need to set the db_file_name_convert and log_file_name_convert parameters in the spfile.

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28273/rcmsynta020.htm#RCMRF126